# C - Manipulating a float from a file

Tags: c

I'm working on an assignment for one of my C-based classes...

This is the goal of the assignment:

**Assignment:**
Read a float number from a file and output it with 2 digits after the decimal point. The number should have at least 8 digits BEFORE the decimal point. Then, extract all digits at even positions from before the decimal point. Print them in reverse order. Then extract all digits at odd positions from before the decimal point and print in order of occurrence.

Example:

Your number is:    12345678.99

Even positioned digits printed in reverse order – 8 6 4 2

Odd positioned digits printed in order – 1 3 5 7

My code (thus far), is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define INPUT_FILE "FloatNumber.txt"


int main ()
{
    //Variables for the digits BEFORE the decimal point
    int ldig1 = 0, ldig2 = 0, ldig3 = 0, ldig4 = 0, ldig5 = 0, ldig6 = 0, ldig7 = 0, ldig8 = 0;
    //Variable for the float number in the text file
    float txtFloat;

    FILE *fp = NULL;
    fp = fopen(INPUT_FILE, "r"); //because we are just reading from a file... the float is already written there
    fscanf(fp, "%.2f", &txtFloat);


    //Print the number that is currently in the text file
    printf("Your number is: %.2f\n", txtFloat);

    //Extract first 8 digits (before decimal)
    ldig8 = (int)txtFloat % 10;
    txtFloat /= 10;

    //Extract last 7 digits (before decimal)
    ldig7 = (int)txtFloat % 10;
    txtFloat /= 10;

    //Extract last 6 digits (before decimal)
    ldig6 = (int)txtFloat % 10;
    txtFloat /= 10;

    //Extract last 5 digits (before decimal)
    ldig5 = (int)txtFloat % 10;
    txtFloat /= 10;

    //Extract last 4 digits (before decimal)
    ldig4 = (int)txtFloat % 10;
    txtFloat /= 10;

    //Extract last 3 digits (before decimal)
    ldig3 = (int)txtFloat % 10;
    txtFloat /= 10;

    //Extract last 2 digits (before decimal)
    ldig2 = (int)txtFloat % 10;
    txtFloat /= 10;

    //Extract last digits (before decimal)
    ldig1 = (int)txtFloat % 10;
    txtFloat /= 10;

    //Print the digits in even positions in REVERSE order
    printf("Even positioned digits printed in reverse order: %d %d %d %d\n", ldig8, ldig6, ldig4, ldig2);

    //Print the digits in odd positions in REGULAR order
    printf("Odd positioned digits printed in order: %d %d %d %d\n", ldig7, ldig5, ldig3, ldig1);

    //Close the file
    fclose(fp);
}
```

In the text file, I have the following:

```
12345678.99
```

The output should look like the example stated above, but instead I am getting the following output:

Your number is: 0.00

Even positioned digits printed in reverse order: 0 0 0 0

Odd positioned digits printed in order: 0 0 0 0

I'm fairly certain my issue has something to do with typecasting. As you can see, I've typecasted `txtFloat` as an int, because that is the only way I can perform the modulus operation. But I think this is likely the reason behind why I am getting all zeros for my output.

Additionally, I am running this program on Windows using WinSCP, PuTTY, and Notepad++. I haven't had a chance to run it on the actual Linux OS yet. I read somewhere that text files are configured differently between Windows and Linux so maybe that is another issue at play? I'm sure there are other problems in my code as well as I'm relatively new to programming. Any ideas on what I've done wrong or what I can change in order to rectify the issue? Thanks in advance!

(This is also my first post on the site, so apologies for any formatting errors I may have perpetrated).

Comment: It would be a whole heap easier to read the number as a string and fix the string.  But your teaching staff may not find it quite so amusing.

Comment: Haha I don't think that would get me far. For this particular assignment, the use of arrays and/or strings is prohibited.

Comment: when calling the fopen() function, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding this statement: `fscanf(fp, "%.2f", &txtFloat);`  suggest reading the whole float number,  I.E. `fscanf(fp, "%f", &txtFloat);`  When calling the fscanf() function, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  I.E. `if( 1 != fscanf(fp, "%.2f", &txtFloat) ) { // handle error and exit }`

Comment: the variable textFloat is a float so divide by a float I.E. `txtFloat /= 10.0f;`

Comment: for completeness, change this statement: `printf("Your number is: %.2f\n", txtFloat);` to `printf("Your number is: %11.2f\n", txtFloat);`

Comment: this output: `Your number is: 0.00` should tell you that the call to fscanf() failed.  (checking the returned code would also have caught that problem.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` ) Then the compiler would have told you of (at least) two problems with the code.   Fix those problems and append an edit of the corrected code to the question

Comment: as you should know, float format cannot exactly store all values.  Rather the value, when it cannot exactly match a float value, will be rounded.  I.E. `12345678.99` is one of those numbers that cannot be exactly represented in float format.   So the value is rounded.  The result is `12345679.00`

Comment: As I ended up discovering, the issue was rounding. Because I assigned `txtFloat` as a float, the result was getting rounded. I resolved the issue by changing the variable to a double instead. I realized doubles have higher precision than floats, and therefore they will not succumb to rounding (at least in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Passing `"%.2f"` format string to `fscanf` is invalid. Just replace it with `"%f"`. Also make sure that the file has single-byte encoding.

Comment: Thank you for this! Changing `"%.2f"` to simply `"%f"` has resolved my issue of zeros in the output. Now however, when I use a float number that has anything EXCEPT "00" after the decimal, the output is incorrect.

For example, "12345678.99" outputs:

Your number is: 12345679.00

Even positioned digits printed in reverse order: 9 6 4 2

Odd positioned digits printed in order: 7 5 3 1